# Staggered data creating additional rows (e.g. Time variable)

Tags: r, data.table

I have this problem in data I want to deal with

Basically in this datatable A:

```
FIRM    yrqtr   happened
   A    2001Q1         0
   A    2001Q2         0
   A    2001Q3         1
   A    2001Q4         0
   A    2002Q1         1
   A    2002Q2         0
   A    2002Q3         0
```

Basically "yrqtr" is the quarterly variable, happened is something "happened" to this FIRM A and is a factor variable.

I want to create a time index variable such that 1 quarter before happened (happened == 1) a time index will receive time index 0, 2 quarters before receives time index -1. Since it is before "happened", "happened" column in that row will receives 0.

The same applies to future 1 quarter after (happened == 1) receives time index 2 and at that row happened will becomes 1 too, future 2 quarter after receives time index 3, happened will becomes 1 again.

I only want 2 periods before and after happened, else will have a time index NA or just omit it.

This is easy to do if this firm happened only once, creating additional time column by using seq() function starting after (happened == 1) and use ifelse condition on "happened", if time is positive then "happened" will be 1 and negative time will be 0.

But now i have two "happened" and is overlapping each other, I want to create additional rows to accommodate the overlapping time.

This is what i want:

```
FIRM   yrqtr    happened    time
   A   2001Q1          0      -1
   A   2001Q2          0       0
   A   2001Q3          1       1
   A   2001Q4          1       2
   A   2002Q1          1       3
   A   2001Q3          0      -1
   A   2001Q4          0       0
   A   2002Q1          1       1
   A   2002Q2          1       2
   A   2002Q3          1       3
```

Hence this is like staggering timeline for two events happened, creating new rows to accomodate the time variable.

Anyone knows how to deal with this using e.g. data.table or do I need to write a loop for it?

This is related to creating data for staggered difference-in-difference estimation.

Many thanks.

Comment: sorry my bad i will correct it now

Comment: do you want to keep happened=0 for FIRM A  and yrqtr = 2001Q4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `happened` column should stay the same as before, here is a possible approach using `zoo` and `data.table`:

```
library(zoo)
DT[, yrqtr := as.yearqtr(yrqtr)]
DT[happened==1L, 
    .(yrqtr=seq(yrqtr-0.5, by=0.25, length.out=5),
        happened=c(0L,0L,1L,1L,1L),
        time=-1L:3L), 
    by=.(FIRM, rowid(happened))][, rowid:=NULL]
```

output:

```
    FIRM   yrqtr happened time
 1:    A 2001 Q1        0   -1
 2:    A 2001 Q2        0    0
 3:    A 2001 Q3        1    1
 4:    A 2001 Q4        1    2
 5:    A 2002 Q1        1    3
 6:    A 2001 Q3        0   -1
 7:    A 2001 Q4        0    0
 8:    A 2002 Q1        1    1
 9:    A 2002 Q2        1    2
10:    A 2002 Q3        1    3
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("FIRM    yrqtr   happened
A    2001Q1         0
A    2001Q2         0
A    2001Q3         1
A    2001Q4         0
A    2002Q1         1
A    2002Q2         0
A    2002Q3         0")
```

Comment: And then to make happened == 1 when time is positive, and happened == 0 when time is negative

DT[, happened := ifelse(time > 0, 1, happened)]

DT[, happened := ifelse(time < 0, 0, happened)]

Comment: Does anyone know why i get this error?

Error in seq.default(yr_qtr - 0.50, by = 0.25, length.out = 5) : 
  'from' must be of length 1

Comment: Maybe use seq(yrqtr[1L]

Comment: Hi what does it mean when you do yrqtr[1L]. Does that mean the first row of yrqtr?

Comment: I think perhaps my data have duplicates and hence it doesnt know which one to create sequence from? Or seq() does not support vectorized operation?

DT[happened==1L, 
    .(yrqtr=seq(yrqtr[1L]-0.5, by=0.25, length.out=5),
        happened=c(0L,0L,1L,1L,1L),
        time=-1L:3L), 
    by=.(FIRM, rowid(happened))][, rowid:=NULL]

Comment: Yeah seq is not vectorized